# Get first line of string with line breaks

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I'm trying to improve a [bash script to extract a quote](https://gist.github.com/iandundas/7863c6c248f76e14a3a8) from the string generated when you copy something from iBooks (Apple book reading software).

I know we can extract the first line of a file via `head -1 filename`, but I'm not looking at a file but a string with multiple line breaks.

An example clipboard looks like this:

```
“When there is no data to guide intuition, scientists impose a “compatibility” criterion: any new theory attempting to extrapolate beyond tested ground should, in the proper limit, reproduce current knowledge.”

Excerpt From
The Island of Knowledge
Marcelo Gleiser
This material may be protected by copyright.
```

The bash script that previously worked (as explained in this [StackExchange answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/197432/405894)) is:

```
sed -E -e 's/^[ ]?[0-9]* //g' | sed -E -e 's/“[ ]?[0-9]?[ ]?//g' | sed -E -e 's/”$//g'  | sed -E -e 's/^(Excerpt From).*//g'
```

It now leaves the last three lines.

Comment: The interesting question is: How do you determine how much shall be copied? Unfortunately you do not provide the desired output. `head` doesn't care whether it is reading from a file or "a string": `echo "$string" | head -1` And there is usually no reason to pipe `sed` output into `sed`. One `sed` call can have several `-e` arguments; and you can even combine the arguments with `;` or newline.

Comment: This is an inherent problem with just cargo-culting stuff you saw on the internet.  It's even worse when the person you're copying from doesn't really know what they're doing either (there's no need for a pipeline of multiple `sed` commands.  sed can take multiple sed `-e` options with a statement in each. You can also use just one `-e` option with the statements separated by a semi-colon `;`).    Rather than ask for another magic command that does what you need right now, you should learn regular expressions and sed.  Actually, perl would be better than sed for multi-line strings.

Comment: If you're not willing to learn regexps, sed, and/or perl, it's probably easiest to just paste it into a text editor and edit it manually.

Comment: e.g. your multiple-sed pipeline can be replaced with just `sed -E -e 's/^[ ]?[0-9]* //g; s/“[ ]?[0-9]?[ ]?//g; s/”$//g; s/^(Excerpt From).*//g'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to run `sed` multiple times in a pipeline.  `sed` can take multiple `-e` options with a statement for each. You can also use just one `-e` option with the statements separated by a semi-colon `;`.  Or even multiple `-e` options with multiple `;`-separated statements in each.

Your sed command is better written as:

```
sed -E -e 's/^[ ]?[0-9]* //g; s/^“[ ]?[0-9]?[ ]?//g; s/”$//g; s/^(Excerpt From).*//g'
```

Note that I added `^` in the second statement to "anchor" the regex pattern to the beginning of the line, similar to how the third statement is anchored to the end of the line with `$`.

However, sed doesn't play nicely with multi-line strings.

Perl does, however, and with its `-p` option it functions as a replacement for sed (at least for simple `sed` scripts like this - more complex sed scripts are better re-written entirely as perl scripts):

```
$ cat /tmp/book.txt 
“When there is no data to guide intuition, scientists impose a “compatibility” criterion: any new theory attempting to extrapolate beyond tested ground should, in the proper limit, reproduce current knowledge.”

Excerpt From
The Island of Knowledge
Marcelo Gleiser
This material may be protected by copyright.

$ perl -0777 -p -e 's/^[ ]?[0-9]* //msg;
                    s/^“[ ]?[0-9]?[ ]?//msg;
                    s/”$//msg;
                    s/^(Excerpt From).*//msg;
                    s/^\s*$//msg' /tmp/book.txt 
When there is no data to guide intuition, scientists impose a “compatibility” criterion: any new theory attempting to extrapolate beyond tested ground should, in the proper limit, reproduce current knowledge.
```

- the spaces (in my sed example) and newlines (in the perl example) after the semi-colons are optional.  They're just there to improve readability, and have no affect on how the sed & perl scripts run.
- this adds another statement `s/^\s*$//msg` to remove blank lines.
- if you want to transform the remaining "smart" quotes into normal double-quote characters, add another statement `s/“|”/"/g;` before the `s/^\s*$//msg` statement. The output would then be:

  ```
  When there is no data to guide intuition, scientists impose a "compatibility" criterion: any new theory attempting to extrapolate beyond tested ground should, in the proper limit, reproduce current knowledge.
  ```
- the `s///` statements can probably be optimised, but without more samples to test with, I'm reluctant to try in case it doesn't work with different input.
- `-0777` tells perl to read the entire file at once, as one very long string.
- `-p` tells perl to iterate over its input, running the statements in the `-e` script and then printing the input after the script has modified it.  i.e. very similar to how `sed` operates.
- Like `sed`, the `-e` option indicates that the next argument is a script.
- The `m` and `s` regex modifiers change how perl regexps deal with multi-line strings.  From `man perlre`:

> `"m"`    Treat the string being matched against as multiple
> lines.  That is, change `^` and `$` from matching the
> start of the string's first line and the end of its last
> line to matching the start and end of each line within the
> string.
>
> `"s"`    Treat the string as single line.  That is, change
> `.` to match any character whatsoever, even a newline,
> which normally it would not match.
>
> Used together, as `/ms`, they let the `.` match any
> character whatsoever, while still allowing `^` and `$` to
> match, respectively, just after and just before newlines
> within the string.

Comment: This is very helpful! I still don't understand how to use this script in my workflow. When I add this to the Automator application like this: https://imgur.com/a/ksw8TEC, I get the error "Illegal division by zero at -e line 1". Can you help me to get this into place? Remember that I want to read from my clipboard, modify the content and return it to the clipboard—I'm not sure if you're script takes that into account. (I don't have to use macOS's Automator and can also execute a Perl script executed on a shortcut, but it might be easier to use Automator).

Comment: Wouldn't an easy sed solution be to concat the lines into one as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758814/turning-multiple-lines-into-one-comma-separated-line?

Comment: This perl script works in exactly the same manner as your original sed script - it take input from stdin, modifies it, prints it to stdout.  Neither this nor the sed versions do anything to integrate with Automator.  If one works with Automator but not the other, then you have probably set up the Automator jobs differently.  Does it work on the command line? Or maybe Automator doesn't like the newlines in the script, try squeezing the perl script into one line by removing them (the newlines and indentation don't affect the compilation or execution of the script).

Comment: BTW, questions about Automator will almost certainly get more and better answers on apple.stackexchange.com than on unix.stackexchange.com.   They have a tag for it: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automator